# Django send_mail redirection

Tags: django

I am trying to include an anchor tag in the email that redirects to the request detail, but it is giving me this error when I click on the link[image]

This is how I sent the mail:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

send_mail(
    subject='Request Rejected',
    message=f'Your request has been rejected by {self.request.user.username}.',
    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    recipient_list=[self.get_object().student.email],
    html_message=render_to_string('request/request_mail.html', {'content': f'Your request has been rejected by {self.request.user.username}.', 'obj':self.get_object()})
)
```

The `request_mail.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'request-detail' obj.id %}">Click here to view details of the request</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the host name is missing in the rendered email HTML. Double check the URL. Most likely you have a relative path rather than a full URL.

Comment: You need to add the protocol and the hostname. In an email you can not use a relative URL since, well, there is no "original" URL.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation this is correct behavior of the {% url %} template tag.

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name)
> matching a given view and optional parameters.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

What you probably want to do to figure out the domain is to use the [request context metadata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) similar to `request.META['HTTP_HOST']`. Or much better if you are using a single domain store the domain somewhere, i.e. in a settings variable (but depending on the use case this is not always what you want).